# How to use import along with require in Javascript/Typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I have `index.ts` and inside of it I have something like:

```
const start = () => {...}
```

Now I have `app.ts` that looks like this:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);

const PORT = 4001 || process.env.PORT;

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
  // I want to import and call start like this : start()
});
```

My `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

and `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "outDir": "./built",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "CommonJS"
  }
}
```

The thing is, I can't use `import` directive at all with this setup, so I guess I am doing something wrong.

If I use `import`, I get :

> Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the
> package.json or use the .mjs extension.

If I put in `package.json` `“type” : “module”`, then I get:

> TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"

so, one pulls another...

How to import this function in `app.ts` from `index.ts`?

Comment: Change `const PACKAGE_NAME = require("PACKAGE_NAME");` to `import PACKAGE_NAME from "PACKAGE_NAME";`. Typescript requires import statements.

Comment: node runs JS scripts. TS isn't valid JS and needs to be compiled before it can be run in node. Either compile the app with TS or use ts-node

Comment: @code Well, I am not able to use `import`. I have update my question with more info.

Comment: TypeScript is NOT JavaScript, and NodeJS can't run TypeScript. TypeScript is run by compiling it to real JavaScript, then running it with Node. You can use [`ts-node`](https://npmjs.com/package/ts-node) for this, which compiles and runs your TS files in one command.

Comment: @EstusFlask I am pretty much new with NodeJS, as well with `TypeScript`. I didn't know about ts-node, but I read about it now.

Comment: @code  (and Estus Flask) Thanks guys, this worked... Its like my first try with Typescript, so I was thinking of it as some kind of superset of Javascript, and that it will magically work on Node :)

Comment: Very understandable :) works magically with Deno though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript Modules documentation for its [export =](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require) syntax suggests (unless it is badly written)

```
 export =  object_or_class
```

to allow the module to be imported as a CommonJS module using `require` in node.

Exporting an object using `export` in  **index.ts**:

```
 const exports = { 
     start   // plus any other exports as properties
 };
 export = exports;
```

followed by requiring it in **app.ts** as

```
 const index = require(".directoryPath/index.js");
 const start = index.start
```

may solve the issue.

Comment: Yeah thanks that worked. But along with ts-node package. Main problem was that I didn't compile TS, as others suggested.

Comment: The answer addresses the wrong point. `export` is supposed to be paired with `import..require` TS construct. This is said on the page that was linked. `const index = require(".directoryPath/index.js")` is still type-unsafe with `export =` or not, while using `import index = require(".directoryPath/index.js")` in uncompiled script would make Node fail.

Comment: @EstusFlask I did think the documentation lacked clarity if you didn't know what it meant already - and it leaves open the question iof wheterh yu can import compiled `ts` code from vanilla Javascript at all In the absence of other information, should I assume `app.ts`  will also fail  to import `dotenv`, `express` and `http` modules because its not using `import=` syntax?  If you could provide a more accurate answer it would be most appreciated - particularly if I can then delete this one!

Comment: I'll try to write a comprehensive answer. There will be no problem with importing compiled TS because it compiles to .js+.d.ts files, so compiled app is legit JS. The problem in the OP is that node ran uncompiled TS. As long as the app stays legit JS with .ts extensions and not using any TS-specific features, it runs. As for importing with require, `const express = require('express')` is also legit JS so it will work as is in both JS and TS, it;s just a function call. It's just not suitable in TS code because `express` is `any` without using special import...requre syntax.